# unable to change directory with CD command

Tags: linux, shell, login, passwd

My situation might not be typical, and this is a reverse shell I got.
I find myself stuck in the root directory; I can't "cd" to change my current directory to anywhere. However, I can list/read files in other directories giving the full path.

Also, the reverse shell would die if I attempted to upgrade my shell in any way.

example: `python -c "import pty;pty.spawn('/bin/bash')"` or just `/bin/bash`

in the passwd file, my user is "mark," and the shell field is missing:

```
mark:x:1001:1001::/home/mark:
```

[image: Extract from /etc/passwd]

However, I have recreated the same user with the shell field deleted on my local PC, and everything functions just fine besides defaulting to `/bin/sh` shell

What is the cause of this weird behavior?

Comment: While your shell session may or may not have been established as a [reverse shell](https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/understanding-reverse-shells/), the behavior sounds much like a [restricted shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html). You (or someone else with root access to the system) would need to examine the mechanism that sets up your reverse shell session and remove any options given to the shell process that might accidentally start it in restricted mode.

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397). I've fixed it for you this time

Comment: I don't think it is a restricted shell, `echo $0` shows that the shell is `/bin/sh`

Comment: and is not PS1, after `cd /home` , `pwd` still show `/`

Comment: is the builtin used? is there an `alias`? `alias cd`. or another binary in path? `which cd`. What is the return value of cd? `echo $?` right after using it.

Answer (score -1):

`cd` is a built-in shell command. And your user doesn't have any shell, to add a shell to your user run from **root** user

```
usermod -s /bin/bash mark
```

Comment: The account does have a shell. When the field is missing the default is `/bin/sh`